# How to enable "streaming mode" in ZAP?

Tags: owasp, zap

I am using zap as a proxy and I can't seem to find a way to allow applications connected to ZAP Proxy to stream content.

In another app, fiddler 4, there is an option to enable streaming mode. By default, fiddler 4 fully buffers content it receives from the server before forwarding to the requesting application. Now this becomes a problem when download sizes are big and the requesting application needs immediate response from the server. Now, the streaming mode in fiddler solves this problem by forwarding pieces of the content to the requesting application. Fiddler is only on windows but I use Linux, and fiddler everywhere still lacks features I need.

Now ZAP has the features but it buffers content.
Is there a way for OWASP ZAP to enable streaming mode?

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment I'm afraid. But you can approach to the ZAP team and open a new [Feature Request](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/new?labels=enhancement&template=Feature_request.md) so they can keep that need in mind for future releases.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26035969)

Comment: "Is there a way for OWASP ZAP to enable streaming mode?" - No, there is not. I do think that answers the question :)

Comment: You can always try to help an user to find a path, solutions are not always inmediate ;-)

Comment: Well, I also answered this on our user group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zaproxy-users/Oel-GnySzuc/gTPSoCofAgAJ So yes as I mentioned there, there is a way forwards, someone could help us implement that feature.